# Improving my AUC scores using the Jaccard Coefficient for link prediction

Tags: python, networkx, auc

I am using the Jaccard Coefficient to predict new links in a network. Every time I try to evaluate the performance of the algorithm, the AUC score varies greatly, from .3 to .8 or so. What am I doing wrong? Could you help me get the correct code? Here is my code so far:

```
#Remove 10% of the edges to create the test set
proportion_edges=.1

edge_subset = random.sample(G.edges(), int(proportion_edges*G.number_of_edges()))
    
    #Create a copy of the graph and remove the edges
G_train= G.copy()
G_train.remove_edges_from(edge_subset)
    
#Make prediction using Jaccard Coefficient
pred_jaccard = list(nx.jaccard_coefficient(G_train))
score_jaccard, label_jaccard = zip(*[(s, (u,v) in edge_subset) for (u,v,s) in pred_jaccard])

#Compute the ROC AUC Score fo Jaccard Coefficient
fpr_jaccard, tpr_jaccard, _= metrics.roc_curve(label_jaccard, score_jaccard)
auc_jaccard = roc_auc_score(label_jaccard, score_jaccard)
print(auc_jaccard)
```